# Return a list of boolean values comparing rows of a list in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column 'y' of True and False in my dataframe. 
It will return a true value If the next row is larger than the previous row of a single column.
For example, if I have a column named 'X'

```
X  y
1  
2  True
3  True
2  False
```

How do I do this without a foor loop. How to solve this problem with the first row of y is blank?

Comment: I believe that @piRSquared solution is better, so please consider accepting his answer... ;-)

Comment: Yours is good too, I will honor your suggestion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.assign(y=df.X.diff().gt(0))

   X      y
0  1  False
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  2  False
```

---

If you wanted to be pedantic and have a null in the first spot

```
df.assign(y=pd.Series(np.diff(df.X) > 0, df.index[1:]))

   X      y
0  1    NaN
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  2  False
```

Comment: It's hard to find a better solution... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [63]: df['y'] = df.X > df.X.shift()

In [64]: df
Out[64]:
   X      y
0  1  False
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  2  False
```